# C++20 Callable Concept in Variadic Function Templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

Currently using g++11.3.0, C++20.

I'm trying to compile this bit of code below, where the function `foo()` is supposed to be able to take an arbitrary number of template arguments, and use them to provide arguments when calling the passed lambda `func`. I wanted to create a `Callable` concept that restricts `func` to only invocables. The code compiles fine as it is. But when I change the line `template <typename ...T, typename Func>` to `template <typename ...T, Callable Func>` to use the `Callable` concept, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo<int, float, double>(main()::<lambda(int&&, float&&, double&&)>)’
```

Code:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
concept Callable = requires (Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

template <typename ...T, typename Func>
void foo(Func&& func)
{
    // T() is used just to show that each template argument is used to provide some sort 
    // of an argument for the lambda.

    func(T()...);
}


int main()
{
    foo<int, float, double>([] (int&&, float&&, double&&) {});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is callable supposed to deduce `Args`?  The type of a lambda is just a unique class type.  The "call" is a function call to an overloaded `operator()`

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry I know nothing about concepts. I tried searching the internet for a pre-existing Callable concept but couldn't find any, so I just tried to make my own...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring `Callable Func` will cause the compiler will only check whether `Callable<F>` is `true`, that is, whether `F` can be invoked without arguments.

You need to pass the argument types to `Callable` to constrain the single `Func` template parameter, for example

```
template <typename ...T, Callable<T...> Func>
void foo(Func&& func)
{
    // T() is used just to show that each template argument is used to provide some sort 
    // of an argument for the lambda.

    func(T()...);
}
```